# "dataframe" or "data frame" spelling in pandas?

Tags: discussion, edits, spelling

What is the correct spelling of this word when it is used in the context of the Python `pandas` library: "dataframe" or "data frame"?

Many Stack Overflow posts have different spellings of this word, and I was wondering if there is one that should be used preferentially.

Comment: Your first search turns up the docs on "pandas.DataFrame", which uses "DataFrame" in its prose as well. What else do you need than that?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi It says "DataFrame", not "dataframe" (see [pandas.DataFrame — pandas 2.1.3 documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)). Note the CamelCase. That CamelCase form is hardly used by the majority of users, other than in the docs. So no, I would prefer to settle on one spelling to rule them all. It will be "dataframe", most likely.

Comment: So many downvotes... Someone here clearly does not like to korekt speling. :)

Comment: Voted to reopen this question. We have a tag **specifically** for this on Meta SO: [`spelling`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spelling): *"For discussing spelling-related edits, **asking about preferred spellings**, or reporting spelling problems on the site itself."*

Answer (score 3):

The correct spelling is ["DataFrame" as per pandas itself](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html). This is how it is used in code and prose. As a class in a Python library this also matches [the language guidelines](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/).
Neither of "dataframe" nor "data frame" are *correct*.

Such a confusion about spelling notably also applies to other languages and frameworks that have the concept. See [this discussion from an R perspective](https://community.rstudio.com/t/data-frame-or-dataframe/144200) but with general data. Wiktionary lists ["dataframe"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dataframe) but without any references and [Wikipedia has per-framework spellings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dataframe). I have found no separate English dictionary that defines the term.

Comment: That's not the answer I wanted... But `+1` for going against the majority, if you think they are wrong!

Comment: I don't think that's quite right for R. Both the spelling with and without the space are [used in the docs](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/R.utils/html/00Index.html). On another page on that site, I even saw it spelled with a hyphen.

Comment: @Laurel For R see the linked discussion. This also acknowledges the different spellings. I'll edit this answer to clarify that "This also applies..." means the inconsistency in spelling, not the "DataFrame" spelling.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to accept both the canonical CamelCase spelling ("DataFrame"), as suggested by *MisterMiyagi* [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/427418/967621), **and** its most commonly used lowercase variant ("dataframe"), but **not** "data frame".

**References:**

I have seen both "dataframe" and "data frame" spellings in the `pandas` context:

> Get Addition of dataframe and other, element-wise (binary operator add).

*[pandas.DataFrame.add — pandas 2.1.3 documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html)*

> Get Subtraction of dataframe and other, element-wise (binary operator sub).

*[pandas.DataFrame.sub — pandas 2.1.3 documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html)*

I assume that the correct spelling is "dataframe", since it occurs more often in Google search results:

- [`pandas "dataframe"`](https://www.google.com/search?q=pandas+%22dataframe%22): 23,500,000 results.
- [`pandas "data frame"`](https://www.google.com/search?q=pandas+%22data+frame%22): 1,800,000 results.

It is also referenced here, albeit in this form: "DataFrame":

> Pandas is mainly used for data analysis and associated manipulation of tabular data in DataFrames.

[pandas (software) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandas_(software)#DataFrames)

Google search for:
[`"dataframe" pandas site:https://stackoverflow.com`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22dataframe%22+pandas+site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com) results mostly in lowercase "dataframe". This may not be canonical, but exceedingly commonly used spelling.

Comment: What do you mean by "accept the ... spelling"? Are you implying that posts writing it differently should be edited?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I suggest to agree on 1 or more common spellings and fix the rest, probably on new posts mostly.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi To be more specific, DataFrame/dataframe/data frame should be on the same list as other common SO spelling mistakes, see [Professional Engineering for the World: Word list for editing Stack Exchange sites](https://pvm-professionalengineering.blogspot.com/2011/04/word-list-for-editing-stack-exchange.html) from Peter Mortensen.